# How can I connect to Android device by IP address for Unreal Engine?

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

I know in Android Studio I can do it with adb in terminal like

```
 adb connect [IP address]
```

But I cannot find a way to do with Unreal Engine.
I am currently using UE4.27.2.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found connecting a device via IP is quite easy.

1. On whatever terminal you like, type `adb connect [device's IP address]`
2. On the target device, allow adb debugging.
3. On UE editor, click 'Launch' -> 'Device Manager'
4. You will find the target Android device on the list.

[UE editor and a powershell terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVvR1.png)